# Add "1 january" to each row of a column containing years

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R studio with a column (YEAR_OF_BIRTH) where each row contains a year (yyyy format), and I would like to create a new column containing the year, but adding 01-01- to each row.

Does someone know how I can do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
df$new_column <- paste0("01-01-", df$YEAR_OF_BIRTH)
```

Or if you want it as date datatype:

```
df$new_column <- as.Date(paste0("01-01-", df$YEAR_OF_BIRTH), format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

Disclaimer:
This is borderline adding fictional information to a data set. I assume you have a good reason to put all these dates to first of january ;)